# MySQL Grouping using group_concat and then Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, subquery

I have a table like this:

[image]

Basically, I want to group all names and give the count of such groupings like:

[image]

Since there are 2 users with cooking and cleaning, 1 for washing and 4 for cooking.

I am trying to use group_concat

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT name) AS name, count(*)
FROM warehouse.test1
GROUP BY guid
```

However, this will not work as I need to group by the groupings and then get count of those groupings.

I am not getting how to group on the groupings and then get the count.

Thanks in advance and I appreciate any heads up!

**UPDATE**
As per the answer I tried

```
SELECT   groupings, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT   group_concat(DISTINCT name) AS groupings
          FROM     warehouse.test1
          GROUP BY saguid) t
GROUP BY groupings;
```

However, I get it as

```
# groupings, COUNT(*)
'cleaning,cooking', '2'
'cooking', '2'
'washing', '1'
```

shoudnt count be 4 for cooking?

Comment: If you get `4` for cooking then you're counting it twice: both the people who only do cooking and the ones who do both cooking and cleaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap this query with another query to coubt the grouped data:

```
SELECT   groupings, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT   group_concat(DISTINCT name) AS groupings
          FROM     warehouse.test1
          GROUP BY saguid) t
GROUP BY groupings
```

Comment: I am getting Unknown column 'groupins' in 'group statement'

Comment: That's a typo, it should be `groupings`

Comment: @Yogi indeed, that was typo on my behalf. Thatnks Barmar for fixing it.